# Phonegap Android link - Download link

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have built a Phonegap/Android app which uses an iframe to process payments and provide a download link for a mp3 - all works fine - until you click to download and nothing happens!

Is there issues with iframe download permissions within an app?  Does anyone have any ideas how to solve?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: The target="_parent" attribute on all links in the iframe works as a workaround by the way.. not ideal though as it takes the user outside the app to download...

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

```
    // Make sure links in the webview is handled by the webview and not sent to a full browser
    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

which could open the link with your WebView.

or inside your iFrame with jQuery (provided there is only 1 link in the iFrame) which will open the link outside of the application:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url;
    url = $("a").attr('href');
    $("a").attr("onclick", "window.open('"+url+"'); return false;");
  });
</script>
```